HSTS and redirection IIS 10
I enabled HSTS in iis v 10.0.20348.1.

Enable HSTS
Enable IncludeSubDomains
Enable Preload
Enable Redirect Http to Https

I was testing my website here https://hstspreload.org and I got this error:

Error: HTTP redirects to www first
http://example.com
(HTTP) should immediately redirect to https://example.com
(HTTPS) before adding the www subdomain. Right now, the first redirect
is to https://www.example.com/. The extra redirect is
required to ensure that any browser which supports HSTS will record
the HSTS entry for the top level domain, not just the subdomain.

For redirection from non-www to www I have a rule:
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}{URL}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

Any help and suggestions to fix the error are welcome. Thanks.

You should  do it from the domain manager, from DNS records.

It seems to be a problem caused by the execution order. Please try to implement your requirement using multiple rules in the rewrite module, something like this:
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^hstspreload.org$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://hstspreload.org/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<rule name="Redirect to www on HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^hstspreload.org$" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.hstspreload.org/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

